# how to get/post Timesheet using xeroizer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xero-api, xeroizer

I wasn't able to find way to post **time-sheet** to XERO api using xeroizer gem.
Does xeroizer support Time-sheet get/post feature?

Answer (score 0):

Xeroizer SDK was contributed by external developer [Wayne Robinson](https://github.com/waynerobinson). You may want to contact him to confirm this.